# Making BlueZ C++ library threadsafe

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluez

I'm looking into the requirements for making this C++ BLE library threadsafe:
https://github.com/edrosten/libblepp

I need some help on how can I connect to multiple BLE devices, or how shall I need to serialize my tasks (multiple writes).

With gatttool it is possible to open (and connect to) multiple BLE devices at the same time.

If I use this library, shall I create multiple instances of `BLEGATTStateMachine`?

In their non-blocking example (https://github.com/edrosten/libblepp/blob/master/examples/bluetooth.cc):

```
//Writes are usually available, so only check for them when the 
//state machine wants to write.
if(gatt.wait_on_write())
    FD_SET(gatt.socket(), &write_set);

int result = select(gatt.socket() + 1, &read_set, &write_set, NULL, & tv);

if(FD_ISSET(gatt.socket(), &write_set))
    gatt.write_and_process_next();
```

Okay, so if I have something to write, and write becomes available it calls `write_and_process_next()`.

However in https://github.com/edrosten/libblepp/blob/master/src/blestatemachine.cc#L476:

It seems it only handles `if(state == Connecting)`. So if I'm already connected, this call seems to do nothing.

However, there is also `send_write_request`, which calls `dev.send_write_request`, which is eventually ends in a socket write (https://github.com/edrosten/libblepp/blob/master/src/bledevice.cc#L119):

```
int ret = write(sock, buf.data(), len);
```

Now my questions are:

1. how to connect to multiple devices?
2. Is it enough to synchronize these `write` calls on the socket to make it threadsafe?

Comment: You should have one socket per connection. But do you have any reason for not using BlueZ? With https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html or https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-lowlevel.html it's relatively easy to program BLE.

Comment: Thanks! I prefer avoiding DBus, but otherwise I have no reasons on not using BlueZ. I was looking for a C++ wrapper to make it a bit easier and found libblepp.